# What would the measurement device show me if I measured the dye concentration at the pipe location where all of the mass is concentrated at?

Tags: measurements, dirac-delta-distributions, diffusion

I was studying the methods for solving the diffusion equation. [Here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Differential_Equations_(Chasnov)/09%3A_Partial_Differential_Equations/9.05%3A_Solution_of_the_Diffusion_Equation) I found an example problem with the Dirac delta distribution initial condition and zero boundary conditions (example  $9.5.1$):

$$ {\partial u(x,t) \over \partial t} = D {\partial ^2 u(x,t) \over \partial t^2} \tag 1 $$
$$ u(0,t) = u(L,t)=0 \tag 2 $$
$$ u(x,0) = M_0 \delta \Bigg( x - {L \over 2} \Bigg) \tag 3$$

The pipe's length is represented by $L$, $x$ is the spatial coordinate, $t$ is the time coordinate, $D$ is the diffusion coefficient, $M_0$ is the dye total initial mass and $u(x,t)$ is the dye concentration.

Apparently, the physical interpretation of the initial condition is this: At the beginning of the process, all of the dye mass is concentrated at the point $L/2$. The interpretation made sense to me once I saw an illustration like the picture below.

[image: illustration]

As an engineer, I always think in terms of measurements. The value of the Dirac delta distribution at $x = L/2$ is infinity. So my question is: If I measured the dye concentration at $x = L/2$, what value would the measurement instrument show me? Is it infinity, or is it $M_0$? Mathematics tells me the answer is infinity because of the Dirac delta distribution, however, physics tells me the answer is $M_0$.

If the answer is $M_0$, can you please tell me how can I mathematically prove that? There should be a way to get from condition $(3)$ to:

$$u \Bigg(x<{L \over 2}, 0 \Bigg) = 0 \tag 4$$
$$u \Bigg(x={L \over 2}, 0 \Bigg) = M_0 \tag 5$$
$$u \Bigg(x>{L \over 2}, 0 \Bigg) = 0 \tag 6$$

Comment: Does the measurement system show the concentration or the total mass of the dye? These are two different things. The former is arbitrarily large and idealized as infinite. The latter is just $M_0$. As an engineer, you must see that the units of (5) don’t match.

Comment: I see, but if that is the case, then why is the $M_0$ even needed in the initial condition? It is infinity whether it is multiplied with $M_0$ or not.

Comment: To obtain a solution, we need to know the (constant) amount of  dye that is present. Otherwise the equations would yield a characteristic curve at any particular time after zero but no scale for it. If you remove $M_0$, you’ve implicitly set the mass at unity in the units being used.

Comment: I understand that the units don't match. I assume the initial condition is actually multiplied by the unit of $u$ times $1 / kg$. So the instrument measures the concentration.

Comment: Please write down your second comment as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Dirac delta is everywhere either zero or infinity, why do we need to multiply it by the initial mass $M_0$? Because we need to constrain the total dye mass we're operating with; otherwise, the solution to the equations will just be a characteristic curve *shape* at each subsequent time after zero but with no *scale* to give concrete concentration predictions.

If we don't include $M_0$ in the initial conditions, all we're really doing is implicitly setting the initial dye mass to unity in the units being used.